# Is there possibility to filter LogCat to show every log invoked by me in the code?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

For example: I am new to some open source library, and want to see every log that creator put in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. When you're using LogCat you're adding the tag to each message:

```
Log.d("YOUR_TAG", "your message");
```

When you look inside your LogCat, there is a search bar. Type your tag (in the case above it's YOUR_TAG). This way all messages will be filtered.

Comment: You got me wrong. I am looking for one-click-solution to watch every logs invoked in code. Not just certain tags, all of them.